# JPA, Hibernate: fields of subclasses are null with @MappedSuperclass and InheritanceType.JOINED strategy

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to persist a `Person` entity, but I keep getting this null constraint violation error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "created_by_party_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (5023, John, null, Smith, null, 1, null, null, 2020-11-11 07:33:31.590766-05, null, null, null).
```

What I have tried:

- With and without the Discriminator annotations
- Setting the value in `@PrePersist`
- Initializing `createdById` in the base class with a default value
- Making the `Party` class instantiable (not abstract), and persisting it directly - THAT WORKS, but it's not what I need

For some reason, the `createdById` is null by the time the SQL gets generated and passed off to to PostgreSQL. (I have verified in debug mode that this field is set, on the `person` entity, when it gets passed to the DAO save call.)

I'm using **Spring boot, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL** to map my tables and classes like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners( value = { EntityAuditListener.class } )
public abstract class BaseJPA {

    @Column(name = "created_by_party_id", nullable = false)
    private Long createdById = 1l;

    /* Getters and Setters ... */
}
```

```
public class EntityAuditListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(BaseJPA jpa) {
        jpa.setCreatedById( 1l );
    }
}
```

The Party class, although abstract, maps to a PARTY table:

```
@Entity(name = "Party")
@Table(name = "PARTY")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PARTY_TYPE_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Party extends BaseJPA implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5434024967600745049L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PARTY_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARTY_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "PARTY_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
    protected Long partyId;

    @Column(name = "PARTY_TYPE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected PartyType partyType;

    /* Getters & Setters ... */
}
```

The `PartyType` enum is registered with an `AttributeConverter`, with `@Converter(autoApply = true)`

```
public enum PartyType {
    PERSON(1), UNIT(2), SYSTEM(3);

    private final int value;

    PartyType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    /* Getter */
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue( "1" )
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends Party implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5747077306637558893L;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    /* More fields ...*/

    public Person() {
        this.partyType = PartyType.PERSON;
    }

    /* Getters & Setters */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the entity listener method is called? Are you sure that there is no other method that might set the value to null?

If all that doesn't help, please create a reproducing [test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) and submit an issue to the [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/).

Comment: Yes to the first two questions...

I should mention that my DB schema is not created by Hibernate, but pre-generated. When I tried to persist the a `Person` in PostgreSQL with the code above, I get the null constraint violation for the `created_by_party_id` field on the `person` entity.

Comment: But when I try to persist with Hibernate generated tables, (in PostgreSQL or in H2, using the Hibernate test-case), the `PERSON` table does not get the `created_by_party_id` column created, which is what I'm looking for. 

If this is a bug, I'll be glad to post the code to the issue tracker. Otherwise I'm expecting and trying to figure out how to get the `createdById` field from the `BaseJPA` to be included in any level of class that extends from it.

Comment: Can you post the full BaseJPA class and also the persistence.xml?

Comment: I posted the test case [here](https://github.com/bwbb/hibernate-mappedsuperclass-bug/commit/8cfb2efa06864de14cd99ddaa5a1a87ff75da30a). The persistence.xml was not modified from the test case, and in my real project I'm using Spring boot (default setup, no modifications).

Comment: Update: I just tried it in Hibernate 4, and I get the same result :-(. Am I missing something with my mappings?

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in the forum since you posted there: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/fields-of-subclasses-are-null-with-mappedsuperclass-and-inheritancetype-joined-strategy-in-hibernate-5-4